# Filtering on index levels in a pandas.DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

If I have a multiindex dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]],columns=['a','b','c']).set_index(['a','b'])
```

I can simply filter the dataframe on a column, for example:

```
df[df.c>4]
```

But to do the same on the level of an index, say "b", I can't do:

```
df[df.b>4]
```

Instead I can do:

```
df[df.index.get_level_values('b')>4]
```

But is there a less verbose way to do this?

Answer (score 13):

You can use [`query`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#the-query-method) for better readability

```
In [795]: df.query('b > 4')
Out[795]:
     c
a b
4 5  6
7 8  9
```

Comment: Good one, thanks. It looks like it has a 20% performance penalty compared to get_level_values, though.

Comment: Yea, [query](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#performance-of-query) performs well for larger dataframes.